# Interrupt 21h function ah=9h doesn't work?

Tags: assembly, console, output

I recently started learning assembly. I'm using NASM assembly under windows and ALINK linker.

I made a working hello world code in console using win32 functions from kernel32.dll. But I wanted to make a hello world program without using win32 api but using only interrupts.

This is the code I tried (hello2.asm):

```
..start:
section .text use32
    mov dx, msg
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h
section .data
    msg db "Hello world!", 0Dh, 0Ah, "$"
```

The batch script I set up to compile is (hello2 as input to compile):

```
@echo off
title asm
echo Wpisz plik/sciezke pliku .asm bez rozszerzenia do kompilacji:
set/p "file=>> "
echo.
echo Nacisnij dowolny przycisk...
pause >nul
cls
echo Kompilowanie 1 pliku...
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
echo Tworzenie pliku .obj ...
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
nasm -f obj %file%.asm
echo Tworzenie pliku .exe ...
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
alink -oPE %file%.obj
echo.
echo Sukces!
pause>nul
cls
echo Otworzyc skompilowany plik? (tak/nie)
set/p "jak=>> "
if %jak%==tak %file%
if %jak%==nie exit
exit
```

It seems to compile perfectly, but when I run the program, the only thing that is done is that all windows on the screen go out of focus, and no console shows up. The hello2.exe process is on the task list for couple seconds and disappears.

**What am I doing wrong?** As I said I compiled working script with using win32 api functions, but this time I wanted to do it without winapi and without c functions extern...

Comment: Seems like your program starts and finishes too fast. Add a key stroke reading.

Comment: How would I do it though, is there a function in 21h interrupt that reads a keystroke?

Comment: `mov ah,1` , `int 21h`

Comment: Ok, wait, I'll see if it fixes the problem

Comment: Note that it's pretty pointless to learn old dos functions unless you are forced to.

Comment: It still does the same thing, also I got an warning which I didn't see before. It says, "Relocs 0: Warning 32 bit offset in 16 bit field" @Jester You said "old", so does that mean they won't work in normal windows like windows 7 or 8?

Comment: Try using WriteConsole and ExitProcess .

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I did and it worked, but I wanted to try to do it without win api functions.

Comment: You can display strings with `int 10h` and read keys with `int 16h`, because `int 21h` doesn't work.

Comment: I found int 10h function reference, but I don't know which one to use: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-10.htm @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Would it be ah=13h?

Comment: Software-interrupt system calls aren't "better" or "lower level".  In a Windows process, they're emulated on top of the normal Windows kernel, rather than actually using the BIOS code.  Learning these clunky old APIs isn't useful for anything, and just makes learning asm in the first place harder.  (The interesting part of asm isn't in how to use system calls.  You can do that from C).  Microsoft doesn't publish an ABI for Win32 system calls, so the only supported way to use the Win32 ABI is through the DLL functions.

Comment: If you wanted to really get low-level, look up how to really make win32 system calls *directly*, instead of going through the DLLs.  (IDK if Windows uses `sysenter` or an `int ??h`).  (google or reverse engineer the user-space wrapper code for a couple system calls yourself).  That might be a fun project, but again not really useful for anything, because unlike Linux, the kernel ABI might not be stable across versions, since it's not meant to be used directly.  See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for some more suggestions on learning asm (and lots of great links).

Comment: @PeterCordes : Microsoft strongly discourages using the system calls directly (at least since NT4) because they aren't expected to the same across versions. They are generally semi-documented in system header files. If one really wants to bang their head on a brick wall, there is a resource that consolidates the system calls numbers for each version of [32-bit Windows](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/ntapi/)  and [64-bit Windows](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/ntapi_64/)

Comment: If you were to attempt to do console input and output you'd have to resort to using the system calls associated with `NtDeviceIoControlFile`, `NtReadFile` and `NtWriteFile`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: What's your opinion on that as a "fun learning exercise", instead of messing around with `int 10h` in 32bit code?  I ran out of room in my comment to discourage it for practical use as strongly as you did, but I meant to!

Comment: @PeterCordes : If you are willing to accept that without conditional compilation the syscall numbers changes between versions may break code - it might be an exercise if you are truly intent on knowing how the MS system call interface works. User32.dll, kernel32.dll abstract it away, but nothing prevents you from reinventing the wheel for a learning exercise. I've used the syscall interface more than 15 years ago, but these days I've got better things to do, so I'll use the Win32 API directly.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I was picturing just writing trivial non-portable programs that work on the version of Windows they're developed on.  It seems to me that this might be a good way to go for someone that already knows a bit about the Win32 API from C, and want to learn about system calls in asm.  Learning a whole new API as well as the ABI seems like an unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 0):

Display string with `int 10h` and read key with `int 16h` :

```
msg db 'abcdef'  ;STRING DEFINED IN DATA SECTION.

mov ax, data     ;DATA SEGMENT ADDRESS.
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax       ;ES = DS.

mov ah, 13h      ;SERVICE TO DISPLAY STRING WITH COLOR.
mov al, 0        ;DON'T REMEMBER WHAT THIS IS FOR.
mov bh, 0        ;VIDEO PAGE.
mov bl, 14       ;COLOR.
mov cx, 6        ;STRING LENGTH.
mov dl, 10       ;SCREEN COLUMN (X).
mov dh, 10       ;SCREEN ROW (Y).
mov bp, msg      ;STRING OFFSET.
int 10h          ;DISPLAY STRING AT ES:BP.

mov ah, 0
int 16h          ;WAIT FOR A KEY.
```

Comment: Wait, but I just read that 10h is a bios interrupt, so I don't think it would work inside an OS like windows?

Comment: Could you "make ES point to DS and BP point to string offset"? Because I don't really know how to do that because I'm a beginner in assembly?

Comment: @KKZiomek : If you generate a 16-bit program, when run on Windows the 16-bit program runs in a virtual machine controlled by NTVDM. NTVDM has basic support for BIOS and DOS interrupts (Not all of them, but the most common ones). NTVDM of course is only available on 32-bit Windows (not  64-bit)

Comment: @KKZiomek On Windows you should consider the Win32 API the lowest level (it many cases it is a thin wrapper over the Windows system call interface). Write 32 (or 64-bit) Windows code using the Win API to do basic input and output.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez This is my rearranged code here: http://pastebin.com/TpTCDWRa For some reason I get error "hello2.asm:21: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand"

Comment: @KKZiomek : Since you are generating 16-bit code you should use `use16` not `use32` .

Comment: I added "$" instead of 0 at the end, and still doesn't work... I did "use16" instead, and still the same thing.

Comment: I think I know what's the problem, maybe "str" is a nasm operand, and it thinks it is an operation instead of variable, i'll change the name...

Comment: I believe in NASM _STR_ is a keyword and it is getting confused. You probably can solve it by placing a colon after `str`. That will let NASM know it is label and not a keyword.

Comment: It fixed it, but now I got an relocation error: "Reloc 0:Segment selector relocations are not supported in PE files **\n** rtype=02, frame=0001, target=0001, ftype=00, ttype=04 **\n** relocation error occured" Should

Comment: @KKZiomek That is because you appear to be linking to a 32bit target, not a 16-bit one. You don't write 16-bit DOS programs and link them as 32(or 64-bit) windows executables.